# Как включить подсветку изменений в vs code как в sublime?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text

В sublime text 3 на полях идёт подсветка, когда я пишу код (подсвечиваются изменения, написанные мной). Как сделать тоже самое в vs code?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже вижу на скрине подсветку. Что с ней не так?

Comment: это скрин не из моего редактора. нужна подсветка слева в vs code

Comment: Это подсветка гита. У вас должен стоять гит, и открытая папка (выбранная в open folder) должна быть репозиторием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему подключением GIT.